# Alexa smart home capabilities overriding one another

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I have an Alexa project for smart home shades that include two range controllers, a brightness controller, and a toggle controller on each endpoint.

The two range controllers, toggle controller, and brightness controller all have different instances and friendlyNames.

When issuing commands to Alexa, anything containing a percentage is defaulting to the brightness controller regardless of how the command is phrased. If I fully remove the brightness controller and attempt to issue a rotation command (range controller), depending on the device, I get incredibly inconsistent results stating it doesn't know how to set the setting. Some devices will work around 90% at first and will then suddenly fail consistently. Other devices wont work at all. No device is consistently working.

If I reduce down to any one of the capabilities, it works nearly 100% of the time.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior and is there any solution?

Capability code:

```
export const ROTATE_CAPABILITY = {
    type: "AlexaInterface",
    interface: "Alexa.RangeController",
    version: "3",
    instance: "Blind.Rotate",
    properties: {
        supported: [{ name: "rangeValue" }],
        proactivelyReported: false,
        retrievable: true,
    },
    capabilityResources: {
        friendlyNames: [
            {
                "@type": "text",
                value: {
                    text: "Vane",
                    locale: "en-US"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "text",
                value: {
                    text: "Tilt",
                    locale: "en-US"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "text",
                value: {
                    text: "Angle",
                    locale: "en-US"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    configuration: {
        supportedRange: {
            minimumValue: 0,
            maximumValue: 100,
            precision: 1,
        },
        unitOfMeasure: "Alexa.Unit.Percent"
    }
}

export const BRIGHTNESS_CAPABILITY = {
    type: "AlexaInterface",
    interface: "Alexa.BrightnessController",
    version: "3",
    instance: "Blind.Brightness",
    properties: {
        supported: [
            {
                name: "brightness"
            }
        ],
        proactivelyReported: false,
        retrievable: true
    }
}

export const BRIGHTNESS_TOGGLE = {
    type: "AlexaInterface",
    interface: "Alexa.ToggleController",
    instance: "Blind.Light",
    version: "3",
    properties: {
        supported: [
            {
                name: "toggleState"
            }
        ],
        proactivelyReported: false,
        retrievable: true,
        nonControllable: false
    },
    capabilityResources: {
        friendlyNames: [
            {
                "@type": "text",
                value: {
                    text: "Shade Light",
                    locale: "en-US"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "text",
                value: {
                    text: "Light",
                    locale: "en-US"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

export const MAIN_CAPABILITY = {
    type: "AlexaInterface",
    interface: "Alexa.RangeController",
    instance: "Blind.Lift",
    version: "3",
    properties: {
        supported: [{
            name: "rangeValue",
        },],
        proactivelyReported: false,
        retrievable: true,
    },
    capabilityResources: {
        friendlyNames: [
            {
                "@type": "text",
                value: {
                    text: "Shade",
                    locale: "en-US"
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    configuration: {
        supportedRange: {
            minimumValue: 0,
            maximumValue: 100,
            precision: 1,
        },
        unitOfMeasure: "Alexa.Unit.Percent",
    },
    semantics: {
        actionMappings: [{
            "@type": "ActionsToDirective",
            actions: ["Alexa.Actions.Close"],
            directive: {
                name: "SetRangeValue",
                payload: {
                    rangeValue: 0,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            "@type": "ActionsToDirective",
            actions: ["Alexa.Actions.Open"],
            directive: {
                name: "SetRangeValue",
                payload: {
                    rangeValue: 100,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            "@type": "ActionsToDirective",
            actions: ["Alexa.Actions.Lower"],
            directive: {
                name: "AdjustRangeValue",
                payload: {
                    rangeValueDelta: -10,
                    rangeValueDeltaDefault: false,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            "@type": "ActionsToDirective",
            actions: ["Alexa.Actions.Raise"],
            directive: {
                name: "AdjustRangeValue",
                payload: {
                    rangeValueDelta: 10,
                    rangeValueDeltaDefault: false,
                },
            },
        },
        ],
        stateMappings: [{
            "@type": "StatesToValue",
            states: ["Alexa.States.Closed"],
            value: 0,
        },
        {
            "@type": "StatesToRange",
            states: ["Alexa.States.Open"],
            range: {
                minimumValue: 1,
                maximumValue: 100,
            },
        },
        ],
    },
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to reach out to the Amazon Alexa developer community or support for assistance. Other developers may have encountered similar issues.

Comment: If you have two range controllers, consider placing them under one endpoint. This can help avoid conflicts and improve command recognition I think.

Comment: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/devconsole/about-the-developer-console.html you can go here for help because I am really sure what to say to you except go to documentation

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/4h4o2r/alexa_now_overrides_my_connected_home_commands/  and the other that may help you is https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-togglecontroller.html

Comment: https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/questions/32381/alexa-smart-home-skill-overrides-my-skill.html this also but for some reason it is giving me 403