# how do I get endpoints of my devices connected in alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I creating a smart home alexa skill, I study a lot of things and I need to use directives but I don't know how do I get the device_id to test in my devices, I use the example "https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/steps-to-build-a-smart-home-skill.html" from this page. I don't understand how I get the devices id's. Anybory know if I'm doing this correctly?

Comment: Bruhh I just https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66879763/alexa-smart-home-capabilities-overriding-one-another commented about thiis In the following question and this man just edited what I suggested hahha thank you for the recognition though I know how to do it Chris Williams

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, the only place I see "device id" on the page you provided is in the comment. Honestly I'm not sure what it is. Maybe it's a documentation bug.

Normally it works like this:

1. Discovery contains endpoint id (one or more)
2. When Alexa sends directive for the device, it includes the endpoint id in the directive. Should be `directive.endpoint.endpointId`.

You can extra data in the `cookie`. Data sent in cookie in discovery is reflected in every directive, when your skill is called.